# Webpack file-loader, how to use outputPath function

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have been working in a project where I need to use the outputPath function from the file-loader, to emit files to different folders, but I had difficulties to understand and making it work.

Part of my code is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');


const fs = require('fs'); // fs stands for file system, it helps accessing phyisical file systems
const BRANDS = {
br1: 'br1.local',
b22: 'br2.local'
};


module.exports = {
mode: 'production',
entry: {
    main: './src/js/main.js'
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'build.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, 
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
                outputPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
                   if (/my-custom-image\.png/.test(resourcePath)) {
                      return `other_output_path/${url}`;
                     }

                    if (/images/.test(context)) {
                      return `image_output_path/${url}`;
                    }

                   return `output_path/${url}`;
                }
            }
        },


    ]
},
```

documentation says that **resourcePath** is the absolute path to assets, I am not sure about this, as my assets folder has another name not assets, does it matter? it looks like: **/src/images**. 
What is context not sure what is my context. When I do a console.log of these arguments it shows **undefined**, and it doesn't emit the images to the right folders.

Comment: Make sure that you are on `file-loader` 3.0.0 or newer. https://www.changelogs.md/github/webpack-contrib/file-loader/

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add your folder name inside if statement.
If your folder tree looks like this:

/src/images/subfolder/

Change your code to this:

```
outputPath: (url, resourcePath) => {
                 if (/subfolder/.test(resourcePath)) {
                     return `images/subfolder/${url}`;
                 }
             return `images/${url}`;
             }
```